# What's the best way to display list of icons using Django?

Tags: django

I'm working on a small project where I have a table named **'icons'** that contains paths for stored icons inside folder **'mydjangoproject/app/icons'** and I have an endpoint **"mydomainname.com/user/icon/< name >"**

I want the user to be able to replace **< name >** with the icon that he wants and he gets in return the icon

For example if the user took this link **mydomainname.com/user/icon/car.png** and used it in an **< img src="mydomainname.com/user/icon/car.png">** tag or typed it in the browser it would work and show that specific icon

What is the best way to do that and how?

Comment: Would throwing it in `mydjangoproject/app/static/user/icon/` and viewing it from `mydomainname.com/static/user/icon/car.png` work?- cause you'd just have to place it in  that first path and it would work: no settings changes, all baked in

Comment: I did that but not working , showing message not found

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to generate dict value

For example send response for user in frontend in this way:

```
icons = {‘icon_name’:’icon_id’}
```

When any user enter the name for icon from front end you can easily get the id for this icon and apply **Django filter** with **Django ORM** to get this **id** from your icon table, and in this way you can access data in fast way **O(1)** better than searching by name